# what's the correct way to get all lists of a site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to get all the lists used in my site and render theire items. Since i'm not allowed to use code i have to rely on something like xlst. However after several days of searching i haven't come up with a solution yet. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex depending on what you are trying to do using the client object model may work.  This allows you to access SharePoint objects without writing code on the server itself.  This does require writing some code but usually a farm admin won't mind it since it doesn't affect SharePoint in any way.

The javascript object model may provide you with what you want.

Here is a link that gets all lists in a SharePoint site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185009

Then to get items from a list

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007

Comment: no sorry, the client object model won't work here, because the site will be for the internet.

Comment: Why doesn't being on the internet prevent the client object model from working?

Comment: it doesnt but i wouldn't like to force my visitors to use IE given the extremely buggy results i got from other browsers. However i guess it could be an option for the backend...

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood your needs.  Is this a browser based application you are developing or a console/windows application?  Javascript works with any browser (Or at least the majority of browsers) so I don't see why this would be forcing them to use IE over firefox or chrome.

Comment: well i won't use it for the frontend output since, but i did some workarounds and i can use it for the backend :)

Answer (score 1):

You can using *.asmx Sharepoint services [SharePoint 2010 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814). Example from Visual Studio: [Connecting to SharePoint Online Web Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/12/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-web-services.aspx)
and
from Sharepoint Designer: [Connect to another library in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/cizi/archive/2010/08/01/connect-to-another-library-in-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)

Good luck!